# Crash Analytics not working ! For Build that is in App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have added crash analytics to my app and I tested the same in test flight before pushing app to live at that time I was getting crash reports and I made Enable BitCode as `NO` in Xcode and I changed in **`Build Settings --> Build Options --> DWARF and dYSM File`** and while pushing app to store In Pricing and Availability there is a section called **BitCode Auto Recompilation** there I **didn't check** Don't use bitcode auto-recompilation. will that create any issue ??? when I open the dashboard of this crashlytics I'm getting warning of this type and since i made bitcode as no I'm not getting the download dysm file from itunesConnect

I did this and uploaded dYSM file will it help ??

1. Select Window -> Organizer
2. This will open up Organizer window containing your archives.
3. Right click on Archive and select 'Show in Finder'.
4. Right click archive in finder and select 'Show Package Contents'.
5. Project.xcarchive contains dSYMs, Info.plist and Products.
6. dSYMs folder contains dSYM file of your project.

[image]

Comment: I am confused.  Are you talking about Test Flight or Crashlytics?

Comment: @droppy I'm talking about crashlytics only... I have live build in app store for that build I'm getting crash reports.. It was saying me to upload dYSM File. and I cannot download dYSMs file from itunes connect so I donwloaded from Xcode organizer and uploaded it will it help ?

Comment: Yeah.  I thought Crashlytics has scripts to automatically upload the `.dsym` files anyway.

Comment: But I have made Bitcode enabled as no in my current build that is available in AppStore

Comment: I don't understand what difference that would make.

Comment: why was it not uploading automatically .dysm file in crashlytics ? whether i made anything wrong ?

Comment: Yeah it's probably not configured correctly.  When I used Crashlytics I think it just uploaded all the time, however I configured it to only do this in Release builds or during Archives, not normal Debug builds, as it would take too long.